# HTML table is not rendering on client side

Tags: javascript

I'm creating HTML table dynamically using JavaScript to insert content via innerHTML into a div on my page. The code works as is without any problems. However, when I view the page source it does not show any data inside the div.

Please help, I need the data inside the div when viewing page source.

```
    function generateHTML(data) {
        var vData = eval('(' + data.d + ')');
        var vHTML = "  <table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'  width='100%'>";


        vHTML += " <tr >";
        vHTML += " <th width='33%' align='left' colspan='2' class='headerStyle'><b>EARNINGS</b></th><th class='headerStyle' width='33%' align='left' colspan='2'><b>DEDUCTION</b></th><th width='33%' align='left' colspan='2' class='headerStyle'><b>EARNINGS</b></th> ";
         //1st row            
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Basic Salary</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Employee PF Contribution</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>PROJECTED INCOME TAX</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //2nd row            
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Supplementary Allowance</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Employee VPF Contribution</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Less : Exemption U/S 10</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //3rd row
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Metro Allowance</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Professional Tax</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Less : Prof Tax</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //4th row          
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Fuel/Conveyance Allowance</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Loan</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Income U/H Salary</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //5th row          
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Leave Encashment</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Loan Interset</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Other Income</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //6th row          
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Car Maint. Allow.</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'></td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>G.Total Income</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //7th row           
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Cash in liew of Car</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'></td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Ded.Chapter VI-A</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //8th row          
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>HRA</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'></td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Other deduction</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //9th row          
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>LTA</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'></td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Total Income</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //10th row          
        vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Bonus</td><td width='16%'>" + vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code + "</td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Income Tax</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Tax on Total Income</td><td width='16%'></td>";
        vHTML += " </tr>";

        vHTML += " </table></td></tr>";
        //New Add for earning, Deduction and Income tax

        vHTML += "</table> ";
        dvSalarySlip.innerHTML = vHTML;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is _dvSalarySlip_? And you are closing an extra **tr** after every _row_ starting from 2nd row to the 10th row.

Comment: `var vData = eval('(' + data.d + ')');` -- that's a bad way to parse JSON. Use `JSON.parse(data.d)`

Comment: @ArunSingh Is _dvSalarySlip_ **id** or **name** of the div? And how do you get the object of that container in javascript?

Comment: <asp:Panel ID="pnlPerson" runat="server">
        <div id="dvSalarySlip">
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>

Comment: Ok, how are you getting this _div_ in javascript?

Comment: dvSalarySlip.innerHTML = vHTML; or document.getElementById("dvSalarySlip").innerHTML = vHTML;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
function generateHTML(data) {
        var vData = eval('(' + data.d + ')');
        var code = vData.EmployeeDetails[0].Code; // added this line

        var vHTML = "  <table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'  width='100%'>";


        vHTML += " <tr >";
        vHTML += " <th width='33%' align='left' colspan='2' class='headerStyle'><b>EARNINGS</b></th><th class='headerStyle' width='33%' align='left' colspan='2'><b>DEDUCTION</b></th><th width='33%' align='left' colspan='2' class='headerStyle'><b>EARNINGS</b></th> ";
        vHTML += " </tr>";
        //1st row

        if(code != undefined){ // added this line

            vHTML += " <tr class='rowStyle'><td width='16%'>Basic Salary</td><td width='16%'>" + code + "</td>";
            vHTML += " <td width='16%'>Employee PF Contribution</td><td width='16%'></td>";
            vHTML += " <td width='16%'>PROJECTED INCOME TAX</td><td width='16%'></td>";
            vHTML += " </tr>";
       }

        vHTML += " </table>";
        //New Add for earning, Deduction and Income tax
        dvSalarySlip = document.getElementById('dvSalarySlip'); // added this line

        if(dvSalarySlip != undefined){ // added this line
            dvSalarySlip.innerHTML = vHTML;
        }

    }
```

Comment: in view page source ?

Comment: on the fly, not possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

View page source will not show modifications made by Javascript. If you want to see it personally, some browsers will let you see it by pressing CTRL+A to select entire page, then right click and click "View Selection Source". If you want users to see it, you will need to use php or some other server side pre-processor language.

**Tips:** Following are some tips on your code:

It seems like you should be using:

```
document.getElementById("dvSalarySlip").innerHTML = vHTML;
```

Instead of:

```
dvSalarySlip.innerHTML = vHTML;
```

Also, you need to remove the extra:

```
vHTML += " </tr>";
```

As many have noted.

Comment: @Arun, we need more information on `dvSalarySlip`.  Is it an ID or how are  you identifying your "container"?  My solution would be if you had `<div id="dvSalarySlip">.  Please show your HTML.

Comment: <asp:Panel ID="pnlPerson" runat="server">
        <div id="dvSalarySlip">
        </div>
         
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExport" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />

Comment: @Arun Here you are showing an onclick function `btnExport_Click`, but above you call your function `generateHTML`.  I am not yet seeing your code that calls the function.  My use of innerHTML above should be correct.  Lets look at more code.  Can you edit your post and add some more code?  You also might want to edit your code to remove the extra `</tr>` so we can check over that for you.

Comment: @Arun View page source will not show modifications made by Javascript.  If  you want to see it personally, some browsers will let you see it by pressing CTRL+A to select entire page, then right click and click "View Selection Source".  If you want users to see it, you will need to use php or some other server side pre-processor language.

Comment: @ArunSingh: If you accept the answer then it will increase your reputation.  Once you have 20 points it will allow you to chat on the forum which is the best approach.  If you have additional questions, just post another question.

Answer (score 1):

Page source only shows the text/string received from the server. It does not show what the browser renders. Once the browser has completed parsing the HTML then it no longer cares about the page source. It only relies on the DOM.

Everything that happens on the page after the HTML text/string is transferred over the network is based on the DOM. The page source actually doesn't exist anymore from the point of view of the browser. The feature of viewing the page source is only a convenience for developers to see what the server sent. Most modern browsers have a similar feature that lets developers see the live DOM: the DOM explorer/viewer in the developer tools menu/tab/pane/window.

When you add the `innerHTML`, obviously the page source doesn't change. Since it's purpose is to show you what the server sent and that `innerHTML` thing happens on the client. To see the changes you should check the DOM explorer/viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try adding this to your code

```
var dvSalarySlipElement = document.getElementById('dvSalarySlip');
```

That should get your HTML object then you could do

```
dvSalarySlipElement.innerHtml = vHTML;
```

Also, you seem to be closing an extra  from row 2 onwards tag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After using your code its not working-- var dvSalarySlipElement = document.getElementById('dvSalarySlip');   if i  use dvSalarySlip.innerHTML = vHTML; then its working.

Comment: Hi can you put your code up on http://plnkr.co/ so we can get a better understanding of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrong markup for html table leads to wrong page source. You have redundant `"</tr>"` tags.
2. Incorrect usage of FireFox instector.

> i m using firefox and i have only one div on page that the name of
>   dvSalarySlip and i m generating html using javascript and in last i
>   append the javascript html in div. it is displaying in browser but
>   when i go on page source then the are blank div. i need the data on
>   page source for another work  –  Arun Singh

Right click on div and select Inspect Element with Firebug from the context menu. Or just press F12 and open HTML tab.

[image]

Comment: @ArunSingh How are you displaying data? What browser do you use?

Comment: i m using firefox and i have only one div on page that the name of dvSalarySlip and i m generating html using javascript and in last i append the javascript html in div. it is displaying in browser but when i go on page source then the are blank div. i need the data on page source for another work

Comment: Do you use firebug to inspect html elements? Right click on div and select Inspect Element with Firebug from the context menu. Or just press F12 and open HTML tab.

Comment: Possibly you are choosing View Page Source. In this case I'm not sure that javascript executes.

Comment: javascript work well and data is display on browser but page source is blank